# How to decode string like "=?utf-8?b?55+l5LmO?=" with Python

Tags: python, decode

I setup a mail server with GAE.
The following code segment shows how I accept and store incoming mails.

```
class ReceiveMailHandler(InboundMailHandler):
    def receive(self, mail_message):
        from uuid import uuid4
        path_info = self.request.path_info
        Mail(id=uuid4().hex,
             receiver=path_info[len('/_ah/mail/'):].replace(at_domain, '@~'),
             sender=mail_message.sender,
             to=getattr(mail_message, 'to', ''),
             cc=getattr(mail_message, 'cc', ''),
             subject=getattr(mail_message, 'subject', ''),
             body = '\n--\n\n'.join(b.decode()
                 for t, b in mail_message.bodies('text/plain')),
             html = '\n--\n\n'.join(b.decode()
                 for t, b in mail_message.bodies('text/html')),
             ).put()
```

Now I get a mail whose sender is `"=?utf-8?b?55+l5LmO?=" <notification@mail.zhihu.com>`
How may I decode the string `"=?utf-8?b?55+l5LmO?="` with Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the codecs module. Since the sender's info also contains arbitrary data about how it is encoded, you're going to need to parse it first then decode it

```
import base64

def sender_decode(sender):
    parsed_string = sender.split("?")

    decoded = base64.b64decode(parsed_string[3]).decode(parsed_string[1], "ignore")
    return decoded

sender_decode("=?utf-8?b?55+l5LmO?=")
```

Comment: It's helpful. I modified you answer a little for it to work. Please review. Thank you very much.

Comment: What am I reviewing? I don't see any changes?